# Powershell recursive search to chose .txt files then output contents of all files into a single .txt file

Tags: powershell, pipe, get-childitem

Any help greatly appreciated.

I have a folder that contains 30+ folders which each have a .txt file that I can search for using:

> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recurse

I want to read the contents of each .txt file discovered and output the contents int a new .csv file on my desktop that also includes the directory of each .txt file contents being displayed.

The question is twofold,

1. how to use pipe and powershell commands to read/show all the words in the files.
2. how to create the csv data that will output both the directory name and the contents of the .txt files.

I can already pipe results to:

> c:\desktop\test.csv -Encoding ascii -noTypeInformation

Answer (score 5):

The following script reads all .txt files within a specific directory, stores the full filename and path as well as the files content into an array and saves it as a csv.

```
$csvOut = @()
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath C:\temp -Filter *.txt -File -Recurse | foreach {

    $fileData = @{
        "File"=$_.FullName;
        "Content"=(Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Raw)
    }
    $csvOut += (New-Object psobject -Property $fileData)
}

$csvOut | Export-Csv -LiteralPath "C:\temp\csvout.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Helpful, but one stage is still missing.
I need to recursively find all the *.txt files because they are contained in separate directories within a grandparent directory.

Example: 
C:\Grandparent\parent1\test1.txt
C:\Grandparent\parent2\test2.txt

I was able to use Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt -Recursive to get the list of all the test1.txt and testn.txt files but then was getting stuck at how to pipe the search into the foreach statement.

Comment: Just add `-Recurse` to the `Get-ChildItem` command. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you.  This is great.  
Could you point me in the direction of what -LiteralPath means (the resources online I can't find a simple explanation.)

Comment: Unlike the `Path` parameter, the value of `LiteralPath` is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted as wildcards. Soure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6

Comment: Thank you Toby - Legend!